# code contracts via generic helper

Tags: code-contracts

Is the use of `[ContractAbbreviator]` attribute in the below sample needed. If yes, then it works even without it. Can any one verify this code for correctness.

```
    /** helper usage class **/
public class UserDataFethcer
{
    public UserData GetUserData(string Userid)
    {
        ContractsHelper.ValidateString(userid);
    }
}

/** contracts usage class **/
public static class ContractsHelper
{
    [ContractAbbreviator] // is this needed or not..
    public static void ValidateString(params string[] stringParameters)
    {
        Contract.Requires<ArgumentException>(Contract.ForAll(stringParameters, strParams => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(strParams)), Message);
    }
}
```

I find that when i use the `[ContractAbbreviator]` , during execution of the `ValidateString` in `ContractsHelper` the lines of code are skipped, when i remove the `[ContractAbbreviator]` attribute, it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you have set in the Code Contracts options for the project. Have you got run-time contract checking turned on?

Comment: yes i have turned it on, but am considering dropping the use of code contracts as it affects application performance. Here is where i got the results from : http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/ContractPerformance.aspx. Meanwhile, i am also going to check with the dotTrace and let you know. Share your comments. Also give me some explanations on the code contract options.

Comment: the application profiling for code given by microsoft gives the following results: using codecontracts increases the execution time by 2ms for the sum function call itself. If this is the case what about the large applications?. Can you please check this and give me a detailed understanding of yours.